# Data not resolving in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, plunker

I have created http://plnkr.co/edit/zDdB0zgBBcWecveMTE3x

when I click on the 'api' link, the data isn't loaded into the view. When I remove the resolve attribute and object, ui-view updates as it should. Why is the data from choiceServiceProvider not resolving?

```
resolve: {
          choice: function() {
            return choiceServiceProvider.get();
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only problem** I see in your plnkr is-- how you call inside resolve:

```
return choiceServiceProvider.get();
```

replace it with following one and see it working:

```
return choiceServiceProvider.$get().get('http://anydomain.com');
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: Doing it as you suggest works. I thought defining the $get method allows me to set custom methods on the provider so I can just do myProvider.some_method()?